# Sammy.js - Rendering outside route

Tags: coffeescript, haml, sammy.js

I am building a Sammy application and I want to use Haml for it. Looks good so far.

```
app = $.sammy '#main', ->
    @use 'Haml'

    # Get some server data
    $.getJSON '/some-data', (data) ->
        # Hic sunt ponies

    @get '#!/', ->
        @partial '/tmpl/maintenance.haml'

    @

$ -> app.run '#!/'
```

I have a template `/tmpl/navbar.haml` that I would like to render before any routing. The reason for this is, the navbar is dependant on some data I receive from the server - again, before the routing.

So how can I render the template outside of the route? Sammy doesn't seem to have a method read for this, only inside a [`RenderContext`](http://sammyjs.org/docs/api/0.7.1/all#Sammy.RenderContext), e.g. a route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used 'location-changed' event, may be not ideal, but seems working:

```
this.bind('location-changed', function(context) {
  var url = escape(app.getLocation());
  if (app.connected()) {
      $('#welcome').html(i18n('text_logged', 'index.php/account/account', app.connected().firstname, 'index.php/account/logout?_url=' + url));
  } else {
      $('#welcome').html(i18n('text_welcome', 'index.php/account/account?_url=' + url, 'index.php/account/register?_url=' + url));
  }
});
```

Where app.connected is session check. And '#welcome' is outside of sammy's $element, and should be present.

You can use context.load for template.

Comment: Ah, thanks. This is not 100% what I will use, but you hinted me to a good solution: I can use `around`, because it's is called in a `RenderContext`, can there fore also has `this.load`.

Comment: Great, I should have mentioned it also though :)